# Second button with same class name not able to get file name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two file upload buttons. When I upload the file, I want to show the file name of the uploaded file in a text box. For the first button, it is working. But for the second button, it is taking the name of the file uploaded with first button.

```js
$("#investment_form").on("change", ".file_upload_btn", function() {
  var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
  var showfilename = $(this).parent().find(".file_upload_name");
  showfilename.val(filename);
});
```

```css
.file_upload_btn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95px;
}
.file_upload_btn input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.file_upload_name {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <label>File 1</label>
  <input id="a" class="file_upload_name" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
  <div class="file_upload_btn">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input id="1" type="file" class="upload" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <label>File 2</label>
  <input id="b" class="file_upload_name" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
  <div class="file_upload_btn">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input id="2" type="file" class="upload" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you find the `.file_upload_name`, you need to do the same with the `input[type=file]`, so it knows which one to target.

```
$("#investment_form").on("change", ".file_upload_btn", function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var filename = parent.find('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
    var showfilename = parent.find(".file_upload_name");
    showfilename.val(filename);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `$('input[type=file]').val()` will return the first occurrence only ( in your case the first file name ).
you should do something like :

```
$(".file_upload_btn").click(function(){
var filename = $(this).find('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
var showfilename = $(this).parent().find(".file_upload_name");
showfilename.val(filename);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it's better practice to attach the event directly to the `file` input, instead of relying on the `change` event bubbling through the DOM.

From there, you can more reliably get the filename that was uploaded by using the `files` collection of the input, instead of hacking around it's string value.

To fix your main issue, you need to traverse the DOM to find only the `.file_upload_name` element within the same `.block` as the input which was changed. To do that you can use `closest()`. Try this:

```js
$("#investment_form").on("change", ".upload", function() {
  var filename = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
  $(this).closest('.block').find(".file_upload_name").val(filename);
});
```

```css
.file_upload_btn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95px;
}
.file_upload_btn input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.file_upload_name {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="investment_form">
  <div class="block">
    <label>File 1</label>
    <input id="a" class="file_upload_name" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
    <div class="file_upload_btn">
      <span>Upload</span>
      <input id="1" type="file" class="upload" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <label>File 2</label>
    <input id="b" class="file_upload_name" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
    <div class="file_upload_btn">
      <span>Upload</span>
      <input id="2" type="file" class="upload" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```